# Setting two fields with the same JsonProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to set two fields with the same JsonProperty value.
If I try to have both of the fields with the same JsonEntity value I will get an error that I can't have two fields with the same JsonProperty.

```
public class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public String Id
    {
        get
        {
            return Id;
        }
        set 
        {
            Id = value;
            IdDuplicate = value;
        }
    }

    public String IdDuplicate { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize it like this:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonEntitys>("{ \"code\": \"test\" }");`

But I get

```
(0xc0000005) 'Access violation'
```

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite recursion in your getter and setter

Comment: You will overflow your stack as Hugo pointed out.

Comment: @HugoRune Then how will I return it and set it?

Comment: Declare a private field and use it. You cannot use a property inside itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it using this way:

```
public class Entity
{
        public String id { private get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public String Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.id;
            }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
                this.IdDuplicate = value;
            }
        }

    public String IdDuplicate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public class Entity
 {
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String code
    {
        get
        {
            return Id; 
        }
        set
        {
            Id = value;
            IdDuplicate = value;
        }
    }

    public String IdDuplicate { get; set; }
}
```